# Delete a Row if a column is Empty

Tags: excel

i want to delete complete row in excel if the value in A column in NULL (i mean empty).

is there any simple query which can do this ?

please don't say some filter way... :( they won't work for me :( if there is any EXCEL FORMULA please help me know friends...

```
A      B      C      D      E
       10     20    ADE     
56     AE     A4    A76
4      EE     AS    EWS
       45     SS    EE
```

i want to delete the 1st and 4th row as column A rows are empty...

Comment: There is no excel cell formula that deletes rows. Place the cursor at the row number, right click and select "delete row" to delete it manually. If you need to automate this process, you need vba..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Put a formula in cell F1: IF(A1="","",ROW())
2. Fill down the whole of column F. This should give you consecutive numbers, or blanks where column A is blank.
3. Select all of column F, Copy, then Paste special... values only. This will stop the numbers changing when you do step 4.
4. Select the whole table and sort by column F. This will put the rows you don't want at the bottom, where you can delete, hide or ignore them.
5. Delete column F once you're done.

Comment: Seems a bit elaborate. It also doesn't matter if the numbers change as they will still be in a sequential order, but this doesn't matter either as the data also will still be in its original order.

Answer (score 1):

Either

- Highlight the whole area
- Choose the Home tab, Sort & Filter, Custom Sort
- Uncheck the option *My data has headers*
- Choose to sort by column A in ascending order
- The blanks will be at the bottom and you can delete this block

Note that this approach will not retain the original order, the following will:

- Highlight from A1 downwards, to the end of the data
- Choose the Home tab, Find & Select, Go To Special
- Select the Blanks option; this will select all blank cells in this column
- From the Home tab, Cells Group, choose to Delete Sheet Rows

If there are a lot of cells in column A then start by scrolling to the last cell; click in this cell and press Ctrl-Shift-Home to select all cells up to A1.

It can also be achieved with filtering, but a formula cannot delete rows.

Comment: Sorting by column A will disrupt the original order. But Select Blanks > Delete Sheet Rows looks promising +1

Comment: Thank you @RichardInglis. The OP hasn't stated that he needs to keep the original order, but it is a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column you want to detect the blank rows in, go to Sort & filter and select filter. You will now see this column has a drop down box, click on this and go to the very bottom and untick the box called 'blanks'. this will now automatically hide the rows which contain blanks.

If you need to use the data in this format just copy and past it into a new worksheet using paste values as I am unsure how programs would it.